# Wrong reported 404 using by Apache (.htaccess rewrite)

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, http-status-code-404

I have this url http://xxxxxxxxx.com/account/session/login/redirect/%2Fhotel%2Frooms%2Findex%2Fhot_id%2F1 which uses Zend Framework (PHP). With help of a .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The thing is i'm getting a 404 Not found. To make sure it was Apache, i exited the index.php main file just when it starts and apache still reports 404. No code of php gets to be executed before that exit.

**EDIT**

The apache domlog for my domain shows this line

```
190.78.208.30 - - [25/Aug/2011:17:48:17 -0430] "GET /account/session/login/redirect/Fhotel%2Frooms%2Findex%2Fhot_id%2F1 HTTP/1.1" 404 25821 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
```

But there are no lines associated in the error_log

**EDIT 2**

If useful i'm running Apache 2.2.19, PHP 5.3.6, cpanel 11.30.2, CentOS 5.6

[image: Print screen of 404 Not found error]

Please notice the 404 not found. When i exit the index.php before executing anything else the 404 still comes up. I can be sure the .htaccess is being read. Following a recommendation i put a

```
SetEnv MYENV 1
```

And is showing up in a phpinfo() in the same domain. I just double checked my access_log and error_log and remain like described above.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The error log should show exactly what file/path apache was trying to load for that request. You can also turn on mod-rewrite debugging to see exactly how things are being rewritten.

Comment: try this one: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your .htaccess file is being read by Apache?
Make sure that By:

1. You have permissions to override values in your website directory. to have this you should have something like this in your Apache configuration file:

   <Directory /var/www/html>

   ```
   AllowOverride All
   ```

   </Directory>

   **replace /var/www/html with the path to your website public directory**
2. Apache has permissions to read your .htaccess file.

This way Apache could read and apply configurations in your .htaccess file.

To test it, set an environment variable in your .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv MYENV 1
```

and then use the phpinfo() function in your index.php file and search for the environment variable. If the environment variable is not present in your phpinfo() output, it means the .htaccess file is not parsed by Apache.